# Were Pope John Paul I's views anything that could imply a support for contraception?

Tags: 20th-century, pope, catholic-church, sex

[Pope John Paul I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_John_Paul_I) was a short lived pope (only 33 days). There are rumours that he was assasinated.

Someone told me that he was quite liberal (as catholic popes can go), and some of his teachings/views could eventually have led the Catholic Church to support contraception.

Is there any basis to this hypothesis? Is there anything Pope John Paul I did, before or after becoming pope, which would imply contraception might be OK? Did he downplay the 'evils' of contraception?

Comment: I voted to close as the question as it stands is unclear and speculative.  You could easily re-write it a little to move from the realms of speculation into facts and it would be a great question.

Comment: It isn't too subjective. I didn't ask a widely fantasy question like "Did John Paul I support contraception?". This question could be answered objectively and exactly with details on what JPI's views were on contraception, with what other bishops/cardinals where saying on his views, was he called a liberal or a conservative by bishops/cardinals?

Comment: I think the questions posed in the text are fine, but the title sounds speculative.

Comment: I have edited the title to more closely reflect the tone of the question.

Comment: @Rory: Much better and asking for facts not speculations

Comment: I supppose, since the Pope is such a powerful figure in the Catholic Church, I had assumed their word was God, and so if they supported contraception, the church would follow.

Comment: @Rory: So much the theory. However, the Catholic Church has an immense inertia and even the Pope would have a hard time turning it around. It would take decades before each and everybody at the lower levels of the hierarchy complies and no longer condemns contraception in his community. Assuming that a new Pope wouldn't turn the boat around again in the meantime.

Comment: @Rory: But seriously, why didn't you just google? [Moral theology of John Paul I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_theology_of_John_Paul_I#Contraception), [The Scandals and Heresies of John Paul I](http://www.mostholyfamilymonastery.com/15_JohnPaulI.pdf)